# How to do a variation in Views.py for add to cart function

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

1. I just need to make the add to cart have variation like for example S,M,L
2. This is not Django Rest Framework i want to make it using Django only
3. I don't have Forms for the variation, if it's wrong can you please help me
4. I'm Following JustDjango Ecommerce but i'm building my own web using the code and trying to add some variation using only Django. without using Django Rest Framework

   <--models.py-->

   ```
   class Food(models.Model):

       class NewManager(models.Manager):
           def get_queryset(self):
               return super().get_queryset() .filter(avail=True)

       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
       discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
       category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
       Package = models.ForeignKey(Pack,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
       per = models.CharField(choices=PR,max_length=2,blank=True,null=True)
       top = models.BooleanField(_('Top Selling'),default=False)
       slug = models.SlugField()
       description = models.TextField()
       image = models.ImageField(blank=False,null=False)
       avail = models.BooleanField(_('Available'),default=True)
       navail = models.BooleanField(_('Not Available'),default=False)

       def __str__(self):
          return self.title



   class Variation(models.Model):
       item = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # size

       class Meta:
           unique_together = (
               ('item', 'name')
           )

       def __str__(self):
           return self.name


   class ItemVariation(models.Model):
       variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       value = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # S, M, L
       attachment = models.ImageField(blank=True)

       class Meta:
           unique_together = (
               ('variation', 'value')
           )

       def __str__(self):
           return self.value

   class OrderItem(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       item = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       item_variations = models.ManyToManyField(ItemVariation)
       quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
   ```

   <--Views.py-->

   ```
   @login_required
   def add_to_cart(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
       item = get_object_or_404(Food, slug=slug)
       variations = Variation.objects.all()
       minimum_variation_count = Variation.objects.filter(item=item).count()
       if len(variations) < minimum_variation_count:
           return redirect("resto:order")

       order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
           item=item,
           user=request.user,
           ordered=False
       )
       for v in variations:
           order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
               Q(item_variations__exact=v)
           )

           if order_item_qs.exists():
               order_item = order_item_qs.first()
               order_item.quantity += 1
               order_item.save()
           else:
               order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                   item=item,
                   user=request.user,
                   ordered=False
               )
               order_item.item_variations.add(*variations)
               order_item.save()

           order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
           if order_qs.exists():
               order = order_qs[0]
               if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
                   order.items.add(order_item)
                   return redirect("resto:order")

           else:
               ordered_date = timezone.now()
               order = Order.objects.create(
                   user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
               order.items.add(order_item)
               return redirect("resto:order")
   ```

<--Error-->

```
  I add a Variation name "Sugar" just for Example when I click Add to Cart this Error show up.

   ValueError at /add-to-cart/item-1/
   Cannot query "Sugar": Must be "ItemVariation" instance.
       Request Method:  GET
       Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-to-cart/item-1/
       Django Version:  2.2
       Exception Type:  ValueError
       Exception Value: Cannot query "Sugar": Must be "ItemVariation" instance.
       Exception Location:  C:\Users\Admin\djangoproj\cafe\cdc\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in check_query_object_type, line 1065
       Python Executable:   C:\Users\Admin\djangoproj\cafe\cdc\Scripts\python.exe
       Python Version:  3.8.3
       Python Path: 
           ['C:\\Users\\Admin\\djangoproj\\cafe\\src',
           'C:\\Users\\Admin\\djangoproj\\cafe\\cdc\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
           'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\DLLs',
           'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib',
           'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32',
           'C:\\Users\\Admin\\djangoproj\\cafe\\cdc',
           'C:\\Users\\Admin\\djangoproj\\cafe\\cdc\\lib\\site-packages',
          'c:\\users\\admin\\djangoproj\\cafe\\cdc\\src\\django-oscar-cash-on-delivery']
       Server time: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 03:05:29 +0000
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuHyZ.png)

[Error Screenshots (Traceback)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBQXE.png)

[I add "Sugar" in Variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7IwS.png)

[In ItemVariation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vZz9.png)

Comment: Please use code instead of images.

Comment: i already edited sir sorry for that, Just trying to follow some tutorial and practicing by making new output  in that code so that i can Understand the concept. thanks

Comment: How are you adding 'Sugar'?

Comment: I add "Sugar" in Variation sir.

Comment: Please be specific... and show your food model too.

Comment: I already Updated sir thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Just below your for loop try replacing:

```
order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
            Q(item_variations__exact=v)
        )
```

With:

```
order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(item_variations__variation=v)
```

Comment: Previously, it was ok to use `v` sso, That should not have happend. Replace the `order_item_qs` completely with the `line` i wrote. Just inside for loop.